# Product of a Laplace and Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, laplace-distribution

I have to derive some statistical distribution for a precision parameter combining one Laplace and one Gaussian distribution. However, from the absolute value arising in the Laplace density I am bit struggle to obtain some known distribution.

Indeed, I am in a Bayesian framework trying to compute some optimal variational distribution $q^*(s)$ for a covariance parameter $s$.
A general result is that $q^*(s) = \log(E_{-s}P(.))$, where $E_{-s}$ is the expectation over all parameters except $s$ and $P(.)$ is the joint. Assuming that my data likelihood for $X \sim N(\mu, s)$ with $s = 1/\sigma^2$ and $s \sim Laplace(0, \frac{1}{\lambda})$. I am interested in computing $E_{-s}(\log(P(X | \mu, s)P(s| \lambda)))$. Formally $P(X | \mu, s)P(s| \lambda)$ can be written as:

$$
\prod_i \frac{s}{\sqrt(2\pi)}\exp\{-\frac{s}{2} x_i^2\} *\frac{\lambda}{2}\exp\{-\lambda|s|\}
$$

IMPORTANT: Here $s$ refers to the inverse covariance parameter, with $s = [-\inf, \inf]$.

For this specific variational inference problem I am looking  for a factorization into $s$, expecting a form where we can identify either a Laplace or an exponential distribution. Indeed, it's a general result since the prior over $s$ is from an exponential family distribution.

My attempts so far were: (1) Distinguish the cases where $s > 0$ and $s<0$, leading to $ \exp\{s(-\sum_i \frac{x_i^2}{2} - \lambda)\}$ in the former case, while $ \exp\{s(\sum_i \frac{x_i^2}{2} - \lambda)\}$ in the latter. However I am not sure whether this distinction is correct. (2) Trying to re-express the Laplace as a mixture of a Gaussian and an exponential distribution (I read that it's a well-known result). (3) Trying to express the Laplace as a special case of some exponential distribution. But without success.

Is there some way to conciliate these two densities ? Do I have to necessarily separate cases for negative and positive $s$ ? Did I miss something ?

Any insights are welcome.

Comment: Why do you care about finding a "known" distribution?  You already know the distribution -  it's just what you wrote down in your equation block.

Comment: @jbowman As you probably already know I am in a bayesian framwork, trying to compute some optimal variational distribution for $s$. I intentionally did not mention this point because it will make the post far more difficult to grasp.  I can add this aspect if you think it's important.

Comment: If $s \sim $Laplace and the centrality parameter of the Laplace equals zero, then you can redefine $s \sim $ Exponential and not worry about the absolute value.  In this case, the Exponential is a conjugate prior for the precision parameter $s$, so you can integrate it out to get the resultant $t$ distribution.

Comment: @jbowman In this case how can I redefine $s$ ? $s \sim Exp(\frac{1}{\lambda})$ ?       $s \sim Exp(\lambda)$ ?

Comment: A Laplace is just a two-sided Exponential; $s \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$.  It doesn't really matter whether you use $\lambda$ or $1/\lambda$, they are equivalent distributions.